# navigation in IE stops working when I add first-letter CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, navigation, linked-list

I'm working my websites navigation and wanted to style the first letter of my slide nav bar.

It works fine in Chrome and Safari, but I have run into two errors in IE and Firefox.

In Firefox, the first-letter styling does not work, however this problem is not that critical, as the nav still functions.

The main question I have is for IE. In Explorer, the navigation functions smoothly when there is no CSS for first-letter styling. However, as soon as I add in this code, the navigation no longer works.

If anyone has any tips, I would greatly appreciate the feedback.

(please open in chrome or safari first to see how it is suppose to look/function)

[click here to view code](http://jsfiddle.net/sstoy/F72qr/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="slide"> +PROJECTS
        <li><a href="#">community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">high rise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >mid rise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">low rise</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">commercial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">institutional</a></li>
```

```
<div id="slide2"> +COMPANY
        <li><a href="index-gamma.html" target="_parent">company</a></li>
        <li><a href="index-newthumbnails.html" target="_parent">awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">people</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li></div>
```

CSS

```
#slide {
height: 15px;
width: 90px;
transition: width 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: width 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: width 500ms ease;
-o-transition: width 500ms ease;
-webkit-transition: width 500ms ease;
overflow: hidden;
float:right;
color:#808285;
font-size:14px;}

#slide:hover {
color:#000; }

#slide li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size:12px; }

#slide2 {
height: 15px;
width: 90px;
transition: width 500ms ease;
-moz-transition: width 500ms ease;
-ms-transition: width 500ms ease;
-o-transition: width 500ms ease;
-webkit-transition: width 500ms ease;
overflow: hidden;
float:right;
color:#808285;
font-size:14px; }

#slide2:hover {
color:#000; }

#slide2 li {
display: inline;
padding-left: 10px;
font-size:12px; }

#slide:first-letter {
color:#000; }

#slide:hover:first-letter {
color:#f00; }

#slide2:first-letter {
color:#000; }

#slide2:hover:first-letter {
color:#f00; }
```

JQUERY

```
document.getElementById('slide').addEventListener('click', function () {

(this.style.width == '90px' || this.style.width == '') ? this.style.width = '563px' : this.style.width = '90px'; }, false);


document.getElementById('slide2').addEventListener('click', function () {

(this.style.width == '90px' || this.style.width == '') ? this.style.width = '291px' : this.style.width = '90px'; }, false);
```

Comment: While I generally don't subscribe to the 2-column colon methodology, I'm reading this in MSDN's docs: Beginning with Internet Explorer 9, the ::first-letter pseudo-element requires two colons, though the one-colon form is still recognized and behaves identically to the two-colon form. Microsoft and the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) encourage web authors to use the two-colon form of the ::first-letter pseudo-element. For more information, see the Pseudo-elements section of the W3C's CSS3 Selectors specification.

Comment: Eureka! It worked! thank you so much. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I generally don't subscribe to the 2-column colon methodology, I'm reading this in [MSDN's docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): Beginning with Internet Explorer 9, the ::first-letter pseudo-element requires two colons, though the one-colon form is still recognized and behaves identically to the two-colon form. Microsoft and the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) encourage web authors to use the two-colon form of the ::first-letter pseudo-element. For more information, see the Pseudo-elements section of the W3C's CSS3 Selectors specification.